# is mount option "sync" valid for all filesystems

Tags: filesystems, mount, usb-drive, storage, block-device

I want to have an script that automatically mounts all USB drives on insert (granted they have a block/filesystem that is a valid partition).

My questiosn is: is `sync` an option that can be applied to all types of filesystems (e.g. vfat, ntfs, ext2, ...)? can I assume I will not get an error message when I mount any given block with `sync` option?

I have seen in the past mount will fail if the provided option is not intended for that specific filesystem type.

so, is `sync` a universal option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
man mount
```

FILESYSTEM-INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS

```
   sync   All I/O to the filesystem should be done synchronously.  In  the
          case  of  media with a limited number of write cycles (e.g. some
          flash drives), sync may cause life-cycle shortening.
```

Comment: Thanks :) I did not know that section exist in man page. now I know :)